# Contador Click botón en C#

Tags: c#, contador

Quiero hacer un boton que cuente las veces que se ha clickeado.
Por ejemplo en el primer click quiero que me entregue un fragmento de texto a un textBox.
Al segundo otro y asi sucesivamente (No mayor a 4 clicks)
Este es el codigo de mi boton. Si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco de antemano.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = -1;
        i++;

        for (i = 0; i > 1; i++)
        {
            DError.Text = "The key is incorrect. You have 3 attempts left.";
            DError.Visible = true;
        }
        for (i = 1; i > 2; i++)
        {
            DError.Text = "The key is incorrect. You have 2 attempts left.";

        for (i = 2; i > 3; i++)
        {
            DError.Text = "The key is incorrect. You have 1 attempts left.";

        for (i = 3; i > 4; i++)
                {
                    DError.Text = "Pray to angels...";
                    DError.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: porque usas un `for` ? no se necesita ningun loop para lo que describes

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo?

Comment: De echo me acabo de dar cuenta que copie mal el codigo, los corchetes van por cada for no como un loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que quieres implementar es tan simple como llevar un contador por fuera del evento click del boton

```
private int i = 0;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
             DError.Text = "texto 0";
             break;
        case 1:
             DError.Text = "texto 1";
             break;
        case 2:
             DError.Text = "texto 2";
             break;
        case 3:
             DError.Text = "texto 3";
             break;  
    }

    i++;

}
```

como veras la variable va por fuera incremetnandose con cada evento

Despues puedes usar un `switch` para cambiar el texto

Comment: Esto me funciono al 100% muchas gracias. Aveces algo tan obvio para las personas experimentadas es algo un poco complejo para quienes recien empezamos. Se agradece mucho tu ayuda!

Comment: Pero este codigo esta limitado a 3 click??

Comment: @ger @LeandroTuttini Este  pudiera hacer el contador hasta el máximo admitido por el tipo `int`. ´private int i = 0;

private void button2_Click(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
     DError.Text = "texto "+ i.ToString();
    i++;
}´

Answer (score 0):

Seria muy simple hacerlo de tal forma que pudieras hacer el contador hasta el máximo admitido por el tipo `int`, solo seria necesario concatenar el texto mas el valor del contador (i) convertido a `string`.

```
private int i = 0;

private void button2_Click(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
     DError.Text = "texto "+ i.ToString();
    i++;
}
```